# c++ classes and static

Tags: c++, class, static, encapsulation

I have a question regarding class design. I want to have a class that encapsulates a bunch of related functions. For instance a Statistics class that would have static functions to calculate the arithmetic mean, empirical variance, etc. Or a physics class that would calculate projectile motion, wave-motion, etc.

How do you reference these function in main? Referring to the statistics example, in Java I would do `Statistics.calcMean()`.

Comment: [How to accept an answer that helped you](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)

Comment: Hey Thanks!! I never noticed the check marks before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Statistics::calcMean()`. You could also use a namespace instead of static class members.

Comment: s/could/should/. This is not Java, static classes are not idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no shared state at all among the different functions, it might be a better idea not to create a class but rather a namespace:

```
namespace Statistics {
   // probably templated on the type of the value and the container...
   double calcMean( std::vector<double> const & values );
}
```

And then you call it from main:

```
int main() {
   std::vector<double> values = create_values();
   std::cout << "mean=" << Statistics::calcMean( values ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `::` to reference static class members: `Statistics::calcMean()`

Answer (score 0):

Define the static methods as:

```
static void calcMean();
```

Invoke by:

```
Statistics::calcMean();
```